# Eclipse how .gitignore file under Windows

Tags: git

I wanted to add a .gitignore file to my project in Eclipse and when I wanted to create one it said there already exists one. 
Found out that there indeed already existed a .gitignore file, but neither Eclipse nor Windows explorer showed it, I had to search for ".gitignore" in the Windows explorer (see screenshot).

Any idea how I can bring Eclipse to show that file?

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with git per se, you will have the same problem with other dot files, such as `.htaccess`. Search the Eclipse help/Google to see how to make them visible - this changes from version to version, so there's no universal answer. It's not entirely ontopic for SO, but your Windows Explorer is probably also configured not to show hidden files.

Comment: Side note to the Windows Explorer: It is really helpfull to enable file endings for all types of files, then you do not have these ugly, "noname" files any more

Comment: Drop windows explorer and use a proper file manager tool like Total Commander :-) Speaking seriously, set the Windows folder settings to show file extensions (it things that your file has a name of "" with extension "gitignore").

Comment: In Explorer, make sure to deselect the option *"Hide extensions for known file types"*, and enable *"Show hidden files, folders, and drives"* in case your *.gitignore* files are created hidden. This will make the files show up in Windows Explorer. I don't know if this also changes the way Eclipse displays files.